# How to truncate tail in a two lines table cell programmatically on iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a a book names shown in a table view. The table view cells has 2 lines `cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2` Now I want to truncate the tail of the second line. Is this possible to achieve programmatically?

Comment: the object that has two lines is the UITableViewCell's `UILabel` `textLabel`. see Pratikshabhisikar's answer for the class reference, but you can just do `cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreadkModeTailTruncation;` if you only want the last line to truncate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
```

However, truncate tail is the default setting for UILabel objects.

For making this clear, please refer to the [UILabel class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html)

Comment: Correct answer, but questionable reference. The docs don't actually explicitly spell out anywhere, as far as I can tell, what the behaviour of `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation` is when applied to multiple lines of text (and it's not mentioned in the comments in `NSParagraphStyle.h` either). However, as it turns out upon experimenting, the behaviour (at least when used in a `UILabel` - I can't testify to how other views with text behave) is that all lines prior to the final one word wrap, and then the final line is truncated - which is exactly the behaviour that we all want 99% of the time.