# UILabel see rightmost content

Tags: ios, objective-c

Normally, when I put a string in my label, the contents that go after the label's dimension will be displayed as "...". I need to see this the other way. ie. When the contents exceed, I need to display the rightmost contents of my label and the left most contents should be displayed in "...".

i.e. For a string "UILabel see rightmost content"

Instead of displaying "UILabel see ri..."

I need "...ightmost content"

For now, I'm doing this by manually editing the string in-accordance with the width of the label. Is there any other way?

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/16848302/1219956

Answer (score 2):

Set the lineBreakMode of the UILabel to NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead.

```
    [myLabel setLineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead];
```