# UILabel truncate tail and skip not complete word

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a single line `UILabel`. It has width = screen width and the content now is (the content of `UILabel` can change)

> You have 30 seconds to make an impression during an interview

Currently, my `UILabel` is truncated tail and the word **"duration"** is not complete

```
self.nameLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

What I want is I want my `UILabel` **still** truncating tail and **only** display complete word.
Like the image below

[image]

Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Comment: you can use truncate middle why you truncating tail

Comment: @PKT sorry for my bad explain in english :( but please see my image, i want to achieve like that

Comment: i think you need inset ?

Comment: The best approach to add padding to a UILabel is to subclass UILabel and add an edgeInsets property.

Comment: `NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle` , It will show last possible word

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378308/uibuttons-title-label-word-wrap-with-tail-truncation

Comment: You need `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` instead of `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` if you want to remove dots from last showing word. If you want to show last word of exact string then you probably need either decrease the font size or truncate it from middle.

Comment: @PhanVănLinh Please elaborate that how can you adjust with this? Can decrease font? Can truncate from middle? Can show what label can show within its width?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
let labelWidth = CGRectGetWidth(label.bounds)

    let str = "You will have 30 seconds till you give us a good impression" as NSString
    let words = str.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

    var newStr = "" as NSString

    for word in words{

        let statement = "\(newStr) \(word) ..." as NSString
        let size = statement.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:label.font])
        if size.width < labelWidth {
            newStr = "\(newStr) \(word)"
        }
        else{
           break
        }
    }

    newStr = newStr.stringByAppendingString(" ...")

    self.label.text = newStr as String
```

Idea is: we split words and try check the width while appending from the beginning + the string "..." till we found the a word that will exceed the size, in the case we stop and use this new string

Comment: thank you so much. your idea is very good and follow it I can solve my problem. but in `statement.sizeWithAttributes` need a dictionary 
and you should add `else{  break; }` when `size.width < labelWidth`. hope you can recheck that

Comment: about `else { break }` you are right, I edited the solution. For the dictionary, you can pass font information and other parameters you have incase you have attributed text.

Comment: I found this to work with single line labels, but it doesn't take into account multi-lines.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this is not possible,with default UILabel, when you set lineBreakMode to TruncatingTail, depending on the space required by the letter/word the OS will truncate it, one solution to fix the issue you can use following properties depending on your match.

**Minimum Font Scale** -- Use this property to specify the smallest multiplier for the current font size that yields an acceptable font size to use when displaying the label’s text. If you specify a value of 0 for this property, the current font size is used as the smallest font size.

**Minimum Font Size** -- When drawing text that might not fit within the bounding rectangle of the label, you can use this property to prevent the receiver from reducing the font size to the point where it is no longer legible.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but try it:

```
nameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
nameLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

OR

If you are using storyboard follow these steps i tried this and it working fine

- Open Attribute Inspector
- Change Line Breaks to Truncate Tail then
- Change AutoShrink to Minimum Font Size

[image]

here are my screenshots of label after and before applying these properties

[image]

new output

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it but it will produce the result like my first image

Comment: if you are using storyboard please check my updated answer it works for me

Comment: It will decrease the font size of `UILabel`

Comment: may be it is the only way to adjust large text into a label of relatively small size. other way is to increase the line number of label

Comment: You're right. Actually question is not clear enough!!

Comment: @TheTiger sorry for my bad explains because i'm not good at english. i have tried to update my answer. hope you can check it